# AWS S3 Event Notification for upload start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried setting up S3 event notifications via SNS topic & was able to successfully get event notifications when objects are created. However in my use case we have large file uploads from the apps that we don't control. These uploads take time. We want to get notified when upload starts (in progress) as well.

I was not able to find any event type that corresponds to upload start!
For large files multipart uploads are used so we get "multipart upload complete" event but still we don't have a clue about when the upload started!

Is there any other way to detect the uploads (start) on AWS S3?

Comment: use aws cloud trail

Comment: @SmartCoder can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an [Amazon CloudWatch Events rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) that triggers on `CreateMultiPartUpload` and sends a message to an Amazon SNS topic:

From [CreateMultipartUpload - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html):

> This action initiates a multipart upload and returns an upload ID.

[image: CloudWatch Events rule]